# Select the top (of 0's and 1's) from multiple records using SQL for php

Tags: php, sql, select, group-by, max

A checklist table exists to state if an item has been collected.

Very simple structure with four fields Code, Object, User, Got.

Multiple up to about 8 users are available.

Example:-

```
Code    Object      User    Caught
id01    Cheese      JS      1
id01    Cheese      DF      1
id01    Cheese      AB      0
id02    Bread       JS      0
id02    Bread       DF      0
id02    Bread       AB      0
id03    Milk        JS      0
id03    Milk        DF      1
id03    Milk        AB      0
```

...and so on.

I know a relational DB would be better.

I'm using the code:-

```
SELECT Code, Caught, Max(Caught) FROM Checklist GROUP BY Code
```

But it doesn't return correctly. I need it to grab just one record for each item that has been checked by any of the users.

So the desired code would return:-

```
Code    Object    Caught
id01    Cheese    1
id02    Bread     0
id03    Milk      1
```

The hopeful end result would be to place into a php script and show all items in the list that at least someone has checked.

Comment: Do you need to fetch **all** items or just the ones that were fetched?

Comment: `group by object` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to alter your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` slightly:

```
SELECT Code,Object, Max(Caught) AS Caught
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY Code,Object
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8e22/3/0)

Since you're taking the `MAX` of `Caught`, you exclude `Caught` from your `SELECT` list, and you want `Object` in your `GROUP BY` since it's a non-aggregate field in your `SELECT` list.

Comment: Can I also Thank You Goat CO on explaining it incredibly well for me. Appreciated. Many Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Code, Caught, Max(Caught) FROM Checklist
```

Comment: Thank you :-) . Sadly that only brings up one record.